# Buid successful but Failed to connect to development server using adb reverse

Tags: react-native, android-studio

My machine is: Ubuntu 18.04, react

First I open Android studio and turn on Virtual device:

Then I run command In two tabs Terminal:

tabs 1: react-native start
tabs 2: react-native run-android

And It show that:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s 27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
>   /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found info Connecting to the development
>   server... warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb
>   reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT info Starting the app...

BUT when I raun command: source $HOME/.bash_profile

and then I run: react-native run-android

It's ok

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem on my Windows machine as well as my Ubuntu Linux machine. The fix that I found for both was to switch to version 10 of NodeJS. (I believe the problem is that Metro server doesn't seem to like v8, v12, or v13 of NodeJS, but v10 seems to work great)